# What does "geth --mine" actually do?

Tags: mining

I know this could be a very basic and stupid question, just that I need clarifications for now.
Executing `geth --mine` results in something like below.

> Generating DAG in progress               epoch=1 percentage=33 elapsed=5m8.892s

Does `geth --mine` do any mining? If so, if at all mined, will the gas go to the default account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does `geth --mine` does any mining?

it's enable mining. The DAG will always be pregenerated if mining is enabled from the CLI using the `--mine` flag.

> if at all mined, will the gas go to the default account?

Yes. If no `etherbase` set and no account found then `geth --mine` don't start. (exit with an error)

<sub>[geth cli options](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options)</sub>

Comment: What is meant by `enable mining`? is there anything else to be done after this to mine?

Comment: @Rajesh What is exactly you didn't understand? It's enable mining process, nothing else need to be done.

Comment: Have studied somewhere that mining is complex process needs to resolve mathematical problems and all, if this command can do the mine, then anyone can mine na. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Yes it is. `--mine` option enable that process, so the `geth` program starts to _mining process_ Here is a good explanation http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/mining.html.